# What application can rotate a TIFF without re-encoding it?

Tags: file-size, tiff, rotation

This is a followup to a question at Apple.stackexchange.com, [Why does rotating a TIFF in Preview increase the file size?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/239488/15745)

One thing I don't like about Preview.app is that even something as simple as rotating an image 90 degrees requires Preview to re-encode the file, adding an alpha channel in the process. This results in a file that is 10% to 20% larger than the original, with no added benefit. This size difference may not matter much on a 5 MB file, but on a 500 MB file, it is a nuisance.

(Interestingly, Preview.app does not increase the file size if you rotate a PDF.)

I gave [GraphicConverter 10](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/) a shot. All I did was rotate the TIFF and save, and the file size increased about 60%—it's even worse than Preview.

I tried [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) on Windows and it also increased the file size about 60%.

Are there any applications that can rotate a TIFF image 90 degrees without re-encoding it and altering the image in any other way? The source of the TIFF is a scanner, which does not offer a rotation feature.

I did a search and all I found were JPEG programs.

---

<sup>(2013 rMBP) -- (OS X 10.11.4) -- (I am open to Windows programs, too.)</sup>

Comment: Hi Kyle. I see [you asked the predecessor to this question at apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/239488/15745). Please [don't cross-post between Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/175991).

Comment: Which site does this type of question belong? I thought that maybe it fits better in Photography.

Comment: Post-processing images, and use of post-processing software, is certainly on-topic here at Photo.SE, but I'd argue that your use, generally just scanning and straightening (or rotating 90°) is more suited to Apple.SE. Your question seems to imply a more general use case than being photography oriented.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't post this as a follow-up question over at Apple.SE?

Comment: I did do that (2 days ago) and I didn't receive a solution that worked. But my question isn't about scanning. It's about post-processing, I think. Can I leave it here and see if anyone has an answer and delete it if not? I'm not trying to spam. I'm just trying to find a program that can do a simple image rotation without re-encoding. The question is not too connected to the Apple.SE, especially since I am not necessarily looking for an OS X program.

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me. This is about photo editing. =)  I'm going to edit your question slightly to refer to the previous question.

Comment: Mostly, when people ask about "rotating without re-encoding", it is because they are concerned about incremental lossy re-compression, which is a bad thing for quality. But since a TIFF is lossless, this isn't a consideration in your case. Still, you may actually want no re-procssing of a file other than a change in the orientation (through a metadata flag or similar). I'm not sure if this is possible, but someone more familiar with the TIFF format should be able to chime in.

Comment: Having said that (my comment above), if all you are concerned about is rotating a TIFF without adding another channel, which you claim the OS X application is doing, then I imagine there are plenty of applications that will do what you want. Check out IrfanView on Windows for one.

Comment: One last comment - personally, I think this question belongs on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @osullic - TIFF is not always lossless.  It's a common mistake that people mix up TIFF (the container) with one of the numerous lossless encoding schemes, particularly where compression is involved.  JPEG and GIF, even Group 3 fax are perfectly valid within the TIFF container - none of them are lossless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is possible and even trivial but I am not aware of any application to do that task specifically.**

There reason why the file size *changes* when rotated is that TIFF files are encoded losslessly as one would compress a stream of pixels components from one corner of the image to the opposite one. If you consider Run-Length-Encoding (RLE) which a common TIFF encoding, it is easy to understand why the same image will not compress to the same size after being rotated. It is equally likely that the file increases in size than it would decrease.

There is an easy way to get around that though and that is simply to change the tag which says which way pixels are ordered in the image. By simply changing the tag from a row-oriented ordering to the equivalent column-oriented one, the image is effectively rotated without any change to pixel data. You can read the details about the TIFF format [here](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm), just search for tag 274 (Orientation).

Honestly I thought no one used column oriented storage pixels so when I initially wrote a TIFF codec, I ignored that possibility for simplicity. As it would happen, one day we received such a TIFF image and my code did crash! Hopefully not many other developers took that short-cut either. It turns out that the file in question came from a scanner which did the scanning and encoding always exactly in the same way but set the orientation flag depending if it was fed a film-strip with frames in landscape or portrait orientation.

Comment: Hi Itai, is there a TIFF metadata editor that you particularly recommend?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used one for a while. TIFF is loosing some popularity it seems, although it is the basis for DNG, so maybe some tools can operate on either.

Comment: If you download [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), rotation can be completed in Terminal: `exiftool -n -orientation=8 [file path here]`

Comment: Related info: [How to set the EXIF orientation flag](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=5629.0), [EXIF Orientation Flags](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html), [ExifTool Documentation](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't matching the compression type before, which at least partially resulted in a larger file size. In case someone comes across this question and is curious, here are the results of a shoot-out of various programs, rotating a 21.3 MB TIFF file 90° counterclockwise, matching for compression type (LZW) and byte order (big-endian) (if given the option):

XnView MP: 30.4 MB

GraphicsConverter: 30.2 MB

Preview.app: 25.0 MB

IrfanView (Windows only): 22.2 MB

Xee: 22.070 MB

ToyViewer: 22.067 MB

The only one of these programs that adds an alpha channel to the file is Preview.

I still don't know why the file size increases, and never decreases or stays the same, but ToyViewer is the program that adds the least to the file size. ToyViewer is also free.